# Differences between ideal and subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $ R=K[x]$ be the polynomial ring over the field $K$ and $S=\{x^4+x^3 , x^2+x\} \subset R$. If $I$ be the ideal generated by $S$ and $B$ be a subalgebra of $R$ generated by $S$, can someone please explain their differences. What would be the elements of $B$?

Comment: Obviously, the ideal generated by $S$ equals $(x^2+x)$. On the other side, $K[S]\ne K[x^2+x]$ (why?).

Comment: because it does not contain $x^4+x^3$. Thank you.